# CKFinder yields: "TypeError: f.config is undefined"

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder, ckeditor4.x

I'm attempting to integrate CKFinder with CKEDitor 4.4.7 and get the following error on page load:

```
TypeError: f.config is undefined  
ckfinder.js (line 6, col 12104)
...;var p=o.indexOf('?')!== -1?'&amp;':'?';f.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl=o;f.config...
                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the sample page:

```
    <script type='text/JavaScript' src='/includes/static/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'></script>
    <script type='text/JavaScript' src='/includes/static/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.js'></script>
    <p>entry box

    <form action='test.php' method='post'>
        <p>

            <textarea class='ckeditor' id='citation' name='citation'>citation</textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'citation', {
                    uiColor: '#FFF6DA',
                    allowedContent: true,
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
                    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
                    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash',                          

                     height:100 
                });

                CKEDITOR.instances['citation'].on('instanceReady', function() {
                    // Output self-closing tags the HTML4 way, like <br>.
                    this.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';


                });                 

                CKFinder.setupCKEditor( 'citation', '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/' );

            </script>
        <input type='submit'>
    </form>
```

The upload button is not being created presumably because of the f.config error above: 
[image]

Here is ckeditor/config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    config.extraPlugins = 'justify,onchange';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';

    config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

};

and the unmodified ckfinder/config.js:

```
CKFinder.customConfig = function( config )
{
        // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
        // config.skin = 'v1';
        // config.language = 'fr';
};
```

What could be causing the f.config error?

Comment: There's no such thing as CKEditor 4.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CKFinder.setupCKEditor` expects an instance, not the id of the editor.

Use:

```
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( CKEDITOR.instances['citation'], '/includes/static/js/ckfinder/' );
```

or simply pass null as the first argument. For more info check http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration

Comment: That got the error cleared out, but I'm still not seeing the Upload option when I click the image tool in the editor.

Comment: Actually, comment out `CKFinder.setupCKEditor` completely. You are passing filebrowser* options to CKEditor.replace() already. Update your code in your question after you do this.

Comment: Commented out the CKFinder.setupCKEditor line, now only using the filebrowser* options.  Still not getting the 'Upload' tab in the image popout.  Just tried it the other way (commented out filebrowser* and added back CKFinder line) - still no Upload tab.  No JS errors.